# Cannot install HP Printer Driver

Tags: 11.10, hp

I can't use my HP Printer in Oneiric Beta

```
~$ cd Downloads
~/Downloads$ sh hplip-3.11.7.run
Creating directory hplip-3.11.7
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.11.7 Self Extracting Archive..............................................................................................
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.11.7)
HPLIP Installer ver. 5.1

Copyright (c) 2001-9 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Installer log saved in: hplip-install_Mon-26-Sep-2011_09:46:00.log

/
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.


INSTALLATION MODE
-----------------
Automatic mode will install the full HPLIP solution with the most common options.
Custom mode allows you to choose installation options to fit specific requirements.

Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : a

Initializing. Please wait...
\
(install.py:2428): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(install.py:2428): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(install.py:2428): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(install.py:2428): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",


INTRODUCTION
------------
This installer will install HPLIP version 3.11.7 on your computer.
Please close any running package management systems now (YaST, Adept, Synaptic, Up2date, etc).


DISTRO/OS CONFIRMATION
----------------------
Distro appears to be Ubuntu 11.10.

Is "Ubuntu 11.10" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


ENTER USER PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the user (vet)'s password: 
Password accepted


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
warning: There are 7 missing REQUIRED dependencies.
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: gcc (gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler)
warning: This installer cannot install 'gcc' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

Comment: Why would you download and install a printer driver from source? 3.11.7 is available in the package repositories of Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem here is that you miss the gcc package..so ensure that you have an internet connection and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Please note that there is already a version of HPLIP in the Ubuntu Software Centre for Ubuntu 11.10, as you can see here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/hplip

Answer (score 0):

This is correct on 11.10, with hplip 3.11.10:

Go http://hplipopensource.com
Choose them:
Ubuntu
**11.04**
laserjet
hp laserjet 1000

Download and run in terminal: `sh hplip-3.11.10.run`